# How to get context of a tapped list item to show details in another page in Nativescript TS

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I am trying to show data from hard coded array list of the tapped item in another page. I tried to make binding context but it dint work for me, please help me out.

home.component.html

```
<ListView class="list-group" [items]="asmaulhusna" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
    <ng-template let-asmaulhusna="item">
        <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row" class="list-group-item">
            <GridLayout columns="*, *">
                <Label [text]="asmaulhusna.name" col="1" class="list-group-item-heading title rtl"
                    verticalAlignment="center"></Label>
                <StackLayout orientation="vertical" col="0">
                    <Label [text]="asmaulhusna.subtitle" class="list-group-item-heading sub-title"
                        verticalAlignment="center"></Label>
                    <Label [text]="asmaulhusna.description" class="list-group-item-heading description"
                        verticalAlignment="center"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </GridLayout>
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

home.component.ts

```
import { ItemEventData } from "tns-core-modules/ui/list-view"
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from "@angular/router";

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    asmaulhusna: { name: string, subtitle: string, description: string }[] = [
        { name: "Title name", subtitle: "easy", description: "adf", },
    ];


    public constructor(
        public routerextensions: RouterExtensions
    ) { }

    onItemTap(args): void {
        this.routerextensions.navigate(["detail"],args);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
}
```

detail.component.html

```
<ScrollView class="page">
    <StackLayout class="home-panel">
        <Label [text]="asmaulhusna.name"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Angular, try the Angular way of handling data. May be you can put list of items in a service, fetch the list of items from that service to load the list view. In the detail component, use the id param from your router, whichever item from the array at service matches with the given id, load that on screen. You will find the exact same sample code if you refer the hello world Angular template.

```
onItemTap(args): void {
  const listItem = args.view.bindingContext;
  console.log(listItem.name);
  // Assuming you have a unique id for each item
  this.routerextensions.navigate(["/detail", listItem.id]);
}
```